# How to assign our old domain name from a non azure server to our new Azure server

Tags: azure, webserver

We are planning to move our web servers to azure however we would still want to use our old domain name from our company.

For example our old domain name is mydomain.company.com, how would we assign this to our new Azure server?

I have talked to our network guys and told us that they could not add the Azure server to the Load Balancer which is owned by our company.

Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

When you got a loadbalancer, you should just add the address of the new Azure Server to the loadbalancer pool. Without loadbalancer, change the DNS a record to the new ip of the Azure Server

Comment: The load balancer is not azure, it is under our company servers.